# How can I encrypt one exist sqlite db in iOS Project with sqlcipher？

Tags: ios, sqlcipher

How can I encrypt one exist sqlite db in iOS Project with sqlcipher？SQLCipher give an method to use command line to encrypt，But no Objective-c API。

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [encrypted-core-data](https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data). It integrates SQL cipher and core data and work quite well. You can use command line to encrypt the db and then load it using `NSIncrementalStore`.